# Application not installing on android emulator

Tags: android

I have developed an application on android.I have used Map overlay class in application.When i try to install the application its showing in console
[2011-01-10 10:39:38 - GeoTourProject] Uploading GeoTourProject.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-01-10 10:39:39 - GeoTourProject] Installing GeoTourProject.apk...
[2011-01-10 10:39:45 - GeoTourProject] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2011-01-10 10:39:45 - GeoTourProject] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-01-10 10:39:45 - GeoTourProject] Launch canceled!
Can anybody tell me how to proceed with it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a new emulator using the google apis which comes bundles with maps.

Comment: varun i have runned the application,,,,whats ur email id.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the name of your emulator.. I guess you will be using an app which has maps. If yes, you need to create the AVD using Google API with the right API Level (and not normal AVD). If you can't find Google API within your "Android SDK & AVD Manager", you need to install from the "Available Packages" option.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new emulator which contains Google API and GPS Support as property from property selection.